# How would I make load more button work in a case like this?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've tried using php and jquery to try and establish a way in which i could make this code work... What i envision is that whenever the user clicks the load more button it will go into the database and load in the next ten data each time they click until there is no more data to be added in that case a message replaces input button saying "No more posts were found". Also the page itself does not refresh instead it stays in place to load the rest of data.

### header.php

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
?>
<?php       
session_start();
// Checks if user is logged in, if not redirect them
if($_SESSION['username'] == ""){
header('Location: index.php');
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
<title>Men's Volleyball</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
<meta name="description" content="To give male volleyball players hope, to ensure they aren't left out" />
<meta name="keywords" content="volleyball, men, sports, sport, scholarships, opportunity" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="load-more.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*function yHandler(){
var wrap = document.getElementById('left-content');
var contentHeight = wrap.offsetHeight; // Gets page contents
var yoffset = window.pageYOffset; // Get vertical scroll position
var y = yoffset + window.innerHeight;
if(y >= contentHeight){
wrap.innerHTML += '<li class="newData" style="background: #09F; margin: 10px 0px;">New</li>';
}
var status = document.getElementById('status');
status.innerHTML = contentHeight+" | "+y;
}

window.onscroll = yHandler;*/
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header" style="<?php echo $display_header;?>">
<ul class="nav-bar">
<a href="profile.php"><li>Profile</li></a>
<a href="gallery.php"><li>Gallery</li></a>
<a href="message.php"><li>Messages</li></a>
<a href="college.php"><li>Colleges</li></a>
<a href="coach.php"><li>Coaches</li></a>
<div class="right-nav">
<a href="logout.php"><li>Logout</li></a>
</div>
</ul>
</div>
```

As you can see I've commented out the code i tried using.

### show_post.php

```
<?php
$eachPosts = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `id` DESC");

while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($eachPosts)){
// if video is empty then echo this line
if(($result["video"] == "") || ($result["video"] != "")){
$account_assoc = $result["account_assoc"];

$result2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($con->query("SELECT * FROM `Accounts` WHERE username='$account_assoc' OR email='$account_assoc'"));

if($result2["username"] == ""){
$identifier = $result2["firstname"];
}else{
$identifier = $result2["username"];
}

if($result2['image'] == ""){
$image = "http://jnvbaghmara.nic.in/images/staff/Blank.png";
}else{
$image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($result2['image']);
}

//change name of echoed dislike variable if greater than one
if($result['dislikes'] > 1){
$dislike = "<label style='color: red;'>".format_num($result['dislikes'])."</label> Dislikes";
}else{
$dislike = "<label style='color: red;'>".format_num($result['dislikes'])."</label> Dislike";
}

//change name of echoed like variable if greater than one
if($result['likes'] > 1){
$like = "<label style='color: #0096f3;'>".format_num($result['likes'])."</label> likes";
}else{
$like = "<label style='color: #0096f3;'>".format_num($result['likes'])."</label> like";
}

echo '<li id="postItems">
<h4><img src="'.$image.'"/> <label>'.$identifier.'</label></h4>
<div class="all-content">
';
//if video is present echo it here
if($result["video"] != ""){
echo '<iframe width="90%" height="90%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$result["video"].'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><br />';
}
//else echo specific line of clone
else{
echo '<p style="color: #555; font-size: 12px;">No Video Available!</p>';
}
echo '
<label style="color: #777;"> '.$like.' </label><label style="color: #777;"> | '.$dislike.'</label><label style="color: #777;"> | 2 comment</label>
<p>'.$result["text"].'</p>
</div></li>';


}
}

echo '<li>
<div class="all-content">
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="load" value="Load More" class="load_more_button"/>
</form>
</div>
</li>';
?>
```

This is where i call the data and echo out the html code

if there is anyway anyone code just write a code that aids me with what i what to use, the table is called posts yea please reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

In order to load more data without reloading the page, you need the page to be able to make an asynchronous HTTP request in Javascript, i.e. you need to learn how to make Ajax calls. In addition to adding some JS for making Ajax calls, you'd need to create an additional PHP file that will receive the Ajax request, make the DB queries, and echo the desired data. Most likely you would want that script to return JSON-formatted data.

I see that your "load more" button is inside a form. If you were in fact going to submit a form in order to make a POST request to the current page, your solution would in fact be reloading the page. When HTML forms make HTTP requests, those requests are not "asynchronous". You could probably make this method work for you purpose but it would be a fragile solution.

So,

- learn how to make Ajax calls.
- learn how to get a PHP file to output JSON-formatted data that has been fetched from your database
- apply your learnings to this project!

Some things you will have to solve for:

- how will your JS to keep track of which results it has already fetched, i.e. which results it needs to fetch next?
- how will you pass those variables (i.e. those denoting which results to fetch) to your new PHP script?
- how will your new PHP script communicate to your JS that there are no more results to be fetched?

If you need more help from the community, consider trying out my suggestions (i.e. try learning how to make Ajax calls and making a PHP script that returns JSON-formatted data) and then ask more questions about a specific problem whenever you hit a road bump.